# transform: scale(n); - different on mousein than on mouseout

Tags: javascript, css, transform

I am using transform: scale(); on a website. I hope somebody can help me with a question I could not resolve by searching in the web.

Here is my code: 
HTML:

```
<div class="hopp_circle_img">
   <img src="..." alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hopp_circle_img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  max-height: 100% !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 0;
}
.hopp_circle_img img {
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.15s;
  transition: transform 0.15s;
}
.hopp_circle_img img:hover {
  display: block; 
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
  transform: scale(1.25);
}
```

That works fine, but I was asked to make the effect different when the courser moves in, than when it moves out. E.g. to scale fast on mouse-in, but slow on mouse-out. Is there any solution for that either in CSS3 or in Javascript?

Thank you 
rabox

Answer (score 5):

Set a the slow transition to the element (`.hopp_circle_img img`), and the fast transition to the element while it's hovered (`.hopp_circle_img img:hover`). So when you leave the element, the slower transition will be in effect.

I've set the [`transition` shorthand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) with different duration and easing, but you can just change [`transition-duration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-duration) or set [`transition-delay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay) or a different [`transition-timing-function` (easing)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function).

```css
.hopp_circle_img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  max-height: 100% !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 0;
}
.hopp_circle_img img {
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-out;
}
.hopp_circle_img img:hover {
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
  transform: scale(1.25);
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.15s;
  transition: transform 0.15s;
}
```

```html
<div class="hopp_circle_img">
  <img src="https://65.media.tumblr.com/avatar_39c12973e9fe_128.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, directly after posting I resolved the topic on my own. There has to be a different transition-time on :hover. e.g.

```
.hopp_circle_img img {
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.15s;
  transition: transform 0.15s;
}
.hopp_circle_img img:hover {
  display: block; 
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
  transform: scale(1.25);
  -webkit-transition: transform 2s;
  transition: transform 2s;
```

}

```
}
```